# How do you figure out if a location is rural or urban in Android?

Tags: android, geolocation

I have a location's latitude and longitude as well as the complete address. How do I figure out if it is an urban area or a rural area? Is there an API service available or something else I could use?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt whether this type of information is available as one man's rural could be another man's urban. It's subjective.

Comment: As I say, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: https://gis-portal.data.census.gov/arcgis/apps/MapSeries/index.html?appid=7a41374f6b03456e9d138cb014711e01

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need [commercial data](http://greatdata.com/rural-urban-data) for that. Rural Urban Suburban Codes is a general designation given by government agencies for each zip code (often used for determining grants and tax incentives - and some agencies define it differently).  You can learn a more from the link: [Rural Urban Suburban](http://greatdata.com/rural-urban-data)  (don’t miss the detail tab at top)

Answer (score 1):

Barry is completely wrong. 
This information is not subjective.
It is available from the US Census Bureau. 
You can also search on Rural Urban Continuum Codes.

Comment: Interesting, although it doesn't seem to be global data.